# Wait For head.ready() and $(document).ready(), Then Execute

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready, head.js

I want to execute some code after the document is ready AND all script loading is complete. I use [head.js](http://headjs.com/) to load the scripts:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    head.js("script1.js", "script2.js", function() {
        // code to execute
    });
});
```

Doing it this way makes starting to load the scripts wait for $(document).ready(). It seems like it would be better to start loading the scripts as soon as possible to avoid a performance drop.

Is there a better way to make sure the document AND the scripts are fully loaded prior to executing a block of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to swap the code around.

```
head.js("script1.js", "script2.js", function() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // code to execute
    });
});
```

the scripts start loading immediately, then when they are done, they wait until the document is ready and then begin executing.

It would be even better if you moved the script to before the closing body tag and removed the domready handler all together.

Comment: the head.js doc says that "the “DOM ready” event such as $(document).ready() is already fired when the scripts arrive", so doesn't that mean it might have already fired?

Comment: @DougieBear Possibly, though even if it has, the domready handler inside will still fire, though it would be unnecessary to have it if that were the case.

Comment: so in that case will it execute the code within, or not fire the .ready event?

Comment: The handler that you pass into the .ready method will be fired either instantly, or after the DOMContentLoaded event happens. If you are absolutely sure that head.js doesn't execute it's callback until after DOMContentLoaded, remove `$(document).ready(...)` because it is not necessary.

Comment: ok that makes sense. so if the scripts load before the document is ready, it will wait, otherwise it will go into the function parameter and execute the code, correct?

Comment: as to your suggestion of putting the script before the closing body tag, that is not possible for me as I'm working within a node on Drupal. the body tags are not within the scope of what I can modify

Comment: In that case i would suggest using the document.ready just to be safe, in the way i used it in my answer.

Comment: Uhhh, you don't need this complication if you just place scripts at the end of the body (I've written an answer that describes more).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.load` to load everything first then execute everything:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    head.js("script1.js", "script2.js", function() {
    // code to execute
    });
});
```

Comment: i need to ensure all elements on the document have loaded so that they can be modified with jquery

Answer (score 0):

Put your $(document).ready() code at the and of all other scripts?!

Comment: the point of head.ready() is to draw on the resources of other (3rd part) scripts, not modify each one individually

Comment: ok, that's a good point. i think the best solution is from Kevin B

Comment: Not to mention, placing a `$(document).ready()` at the end of your page makes the `$(document).ready()` not needed.

Comment: @KevinB makes it sense to place the head.js() call to the end of the document? what do you think?

Comment: @algorhythm That does make sense, it's just that if you placed that at the end of the document, $(document).ready() wouldn't be needed because the document would be ready by the time $(document).ready() was executed. :p

Comment: @KevinB yes, it makes sense... it too late for me tonight

Answer (score 0):

You are making the way too complicated.  If you want the document to load first, then your scripts to load and then you can execute some code, then just put script tags at the end of the document right before `</body>` like this:

```
<head>
</head>
<body>

Your regular HTML content here
<script src="script1.js"></script>
<script src="script2.js"></script>
<script>
// Put code here that you want to execute when document and scripts are ready
</script>
</body>
```

You don't need dynamic loading with callbacks for the simple cause you've described.

Comment: unfortunately I can't do this as I'm working within a node in Drupal. the body tags are outside of the scope of what I can modify. i can only add code to an inner div within the document

Comment: Perhaps you should have mentioned that in your question then.

Comment: i try simplify and generalize questions rather than convolute the issue with specific complications. do you agree with @KevinB's solution with this in mind?

Comment: Leaving out the specifics of your situation lessens the possibility that someone rethinks your overall problem and offers you an even better solution to your particular situation than the one you were currently pursuing.  IMO, you are always better off if you describe the bigger picture problem.  Too many people ask how to implement the solution they are pursuing rather than describe the problem they are trying to solve which may have many other types of solutions.  I still don't know what constraints you're under to know what the best option is, but Kevin's answer seems like it would work.